# puppet site.pp applying node definition config for nodes with same hostname prefix

Tags: puppet

I have following server hostnames.

```
appserver-mgr1
appserver-mgr2
appserver-wkr1
appserver-wkr2
```

I want to apply a specific node configuration to all these servers.

How do I define a unique node definition in `site.pp` file for these set of servers using the `appserver-` prefix?

Currently I'm using default node definition.

```
node 'default' {
        include appserver
}
```

If a new set of servers come as,

```
esb1
esb2
elb1
```

how do I cope up with these changes and modify `site.pp` file accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodes can be declared using regular expressions.

```
node /^appserver-/ {
    include appserver
}
```